# Function executed while compiling en Elixir program

Tags: elixir

I'm having this strange behavior that drives me nutt!
I have the following Plug which checks if API client actually provided the correct API key in the `x-api-key` header:

```
defmodule APIServer.APIKeyAuthPlug do

  # import Plug.Conn
  require Logger
  alias APIServer.Util

  def init(opts) do
    {:ok, options} = opts[:auth]
    apikey = options[:apikey]
    Logger.debug("API key is #{inspect(apikey)}")
    apikey
  end
  
  def call(conn, key) do
    conn_key = Plug.Conn.get_req_header(conn, "x-api-key") |> hd
    Logger.debug("Registered key #{inspect(key)}")
    # rest of the call function
  end
end
```

The plug is inserted in the plug chain in the router:

```
  plug Plug.Logger, log: :info
  plug APIKeyAuthPlug,
    auth: Application.fetch_env(:probe_server,  APIServer.APIKeyAuthPlug)
  plug(:match)
  plug(:dispatch)
```

And the correct key itself is defined as en environment variable and is read in `config.exs`:

```
config :api_server,  APIServer.APIKeyAuthPlug,
  apikey: System.get_env("API_SERVER_APIKEY") || "XYZ"
```

Now, when I compile that code, the line `Logger.debug("API key is #{inspect(apikey)}")` in the `init` function (and only that function)  gets actually executed :

```
maurycy@kali> mix compile
Compiling 2 files (.ex)

16:17:59.774 [debug] API key is "XYZ"
```

Any idea ?

Comment: most probably init\1 is evaluated by a macro from phoenix when generating the pipeline, typical compile-time code execution.

Comment: @Daniel I doubt there is _phoenix_ at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to [`Plug.Builder.plug/2`](https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/v1.11.1/lib/plug/builder.ex#L180) (`plug APIKeyAuthPlug, ...`) in the router results in the call to `init/1` during compilation time unless `mode` is explicitly set to `:runtime` instead of default `:compile` https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/v1.11.1/lib/plug/builder.ex#L275

Setting [`init_mode: :runtime`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Builder.html?#module-options) would resolve the issue.